# msvcr100.dll Error - WinXP x64

Tags: 64-bit, windows-xp, redistributable, vcredist

I am attempting to run a program created in VS2010, on an XP 64bit system. It has run fine on XP-SP3 32bit as well as all Windows 7 versions. However when running on XP 64bit it just crashes when trying to load displaying an error referencing:
ModName: msvcr100.dll ModVer: 10.0.30319.1 Offset:00000000000760d9

I realise the file it references is to do with the 2010 vcredist, which are installed with the program and after checking I had the latest versions found that the ones we were installing required XP-sp3 (which doesn't exist for 64bit XP). So I have tried installing the latest 2010-SP1 Redistributable (which doesn't say it requires XP-SP3) yet the same error still applies.

Has anybody had an error like this when trying to run a program on XP 64bit? Am I possibly looking in the wrong direction in thinking it is caused by the vcredists? Or is it simply impossible to run a program that requires the 2010 vcredists on an XP OS that hasn't got SP3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved, it was some old code that made up part of the splash screen on our program and nothing seemingly to do with the vcredists. The program seems to run fine on XP SP2 so evidently it is possible :)